# Split with a multicharacter regex pattern and keep delimiters

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have next string and regex for splitting it:

```
val str = "this is #[loc] sparta"
val regex = "((?<=( #\\[\\w{3,100}\\] ))|(?=( #\\[\\w{3,100}\\] )))"
print(str.split(Regex(regex)))

//print - [this is,  #[loc] , sparta]
```

Works fine. But in develop I did not realize when in #[***] block must be a not only text (\w) - he have and "-" and numbers (UUID), and my correct blocks is -

```
val str = "this is #[loc_75acca83-a39b-4df1-8c3c-b690df00db62]"
```

and in this case regex don't work.

How to change this part - "\w{3,100}" for new requirements?

I try change to any - "\.{3,100}" - not work

Comment: just use `.{3,100}` not `\.{3,100}`

Comment: @ran_0315 omg, my bad. Really stupid mistake from my. Thank you!

Comment: @abbath0767 `.` may match across any `]` and `#[` chars, use `[^\]\[]` instead of a `.`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue, you may replace your regex with

```
val regex = """((?<=( #\[[^\]\[]{3,100}] ))|(?=( #\[[^\]\[]{3,100}] )))"""
```

The `\w` can be replaced with `[^\]\[]` that matches any char but `[` and `]`.

Note the use of a raw string literal, `"""..."""`, that allows the use of a single backslash as a regex escape.

See the [Kotlin online demo](http://rextester.com/TEOY19586).

Alternatively, you may use the following method to split and keep delimiters:

```
private fun splitKeepDelims(s: String, rx: Regex, keep_empty: Boolean = true) : MutableList<String> {
    var res = mutableListOf<String>() // Declare the mutable list var
    var start = 0                     // Define var for substring start pos
    rx.findAll(s).forEach {           // Looking for matches     
        val substr_before = s.substring(start, it.range.first()) // // Substring before match start
        if (substr_before.length > 0 || keep_empty) {
            res.add(substr_before)      // Adding substring before match start
        }
        res.add(it.value)               // Adding match          
        start = it.range.last()+1       // Updating start pos of next substring before match
    }
    if ( start != s.length ) res.add(s.substring(start))  // Adding text after last match if any
    return res
}
```

Then, just use it like

```
val str = "this is #[loc_75acca83-a39b-4df1-8c3c-b690df00db62] sparta"
val regex = """#\[[\]\[]+]""".toRegex()
print(splitKeepDelims(str, regex))
// => [this is , #[loc_75acca83-a39b-4df1-8c3c-b690df00db62],  sparta]
```

See the [Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/OHNP94148).

The `\[[^\]\[]+]` pattern matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]+` - 1+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.